# Connect to database and write data from range in sheet

Tags: sql, vba

can someone help me with this code please? I am new to vba
I need to upload data from sheet xx, and the entire column A until it hits the first blank value in this column. It shows me run time error, incorrect syntax near 'true' on line with **sqlstr**

Thank you

```
 Sub Upload()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim i As Integer
Dim ExpID As String

i = 2

Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) > 0
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
ExpID = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
End If

    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    sqlstr = "Insert into xxx.tblBillingInvoicesPrint (InvoiceID) values '" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select & "'"
    conn.Execute sqlstr

    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi , have you tried  "ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)" ?  (so removing .select)

Comment: Hello, still the same problem even without the .select

Comment: umm , you may try running a simple sentence first , so we can understand better where the error is , something like : sqlstr = "Insert into xxx.tblBillingInvoicesPrint (InvoiceID) values '7777'" , does this work?